# Define an operator to enclose text in braces without going into visual mode?

Tags: vim

This function defines an operator which encloses in braces text moved over in normal mode only. The operator works just fine as it is.

```
function! EncloseInBraces(type)
 exe "normal! `[v`]\<esc>a}\<esc>`<i{\<esc>"
endfunction

nnoremap <f4>  :set opfunc=EncloseInBraces<CR>g@
```

However, it needs to go into visual mode in order to position `` `< ``  where `'[` was.

How can I define such an operator without going into visual mode?

Comment: https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround

Comment: Yes, but then I and whoever else happens to read this post learn nothing about vim.

Comment: Visual mode *is* how you define operators.

Comment: @nicolai.rostov: Then read the sources for `vim-surround`, and also read the sources of other plugins from the same author.  You'll be learning from _the_ grand master.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use visual mode to apply the operator; it's just a convenient way to implement an operator. To illustrate, here is a variant of your operator function that uses a named mark (via `ma` / `` `a ``) to save and return to the beginning of the moved-over text:

```
function! EncloseInBraces(type)
    exe "normal! `[ma`]a}\<esc>`ai{\<esc>"
endfunction
```

You could also use `getpos()` / `setpos()`; that's more cumbersome, but would avoid clobbering the visual selection or a mark. Or you could use those functions to save / restore the `'<,'>` marks in your function.